# Delete specific cookies from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

How can I delete specific cookies from Google Chrome?

I have cookies from a website that recently got updated, and I need to clean up the existing cookies, but I don't want to delete any other cookies that I have in the browser.

Comment: The answer which was accepted in 2012 is no longer valid. Please consider accepting a different answer, such as https://superuser.com/a/920604/731724, instead.

Answer (score 34):

On Windows and Linux, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd>. On OS X, press <kbd>⌥</kbd>-<kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>i</kbd> instead.

Alternatively, open the *Developer Tools* pane from the *Tools* menu.

Open the *Resources* pane, and delete the cookies you want to delete.

[image: Chrome developer tools - delete cookies]

Comment: Ctrl+J for Chromium 17 on Linux, at least, opens the downloads page. Ctrl+Shift+I opens the inspector for reference. I don't know if the same shortcut is applicable for Windows, though.

Comment: J (note: capital J) opens the dev-tools. j (note: lower j) opens download.

Comment: If you are still wondering, you can use the X marked button at the bottom or the delete button.

Comment: F12 can also be used, which is quicker.

Comment: Note: if the host "unexpectedly closed the connection" then Chrome doesn't list the cookies, and you'll need to use the user settings menu.

Comment: In Chrome 71 (Windows) Developer Tools, the cookies are now under the Application tab, then on the left side, Storage > Cookies.

Answer (score 16):

Here's a command-line solution for deleting specific cookies from Chrome.
Cookies are stored in an sqlite database file:

- on Linux: `~/.config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies`
- on Windows: `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cookies`
- on Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Cookies`

You can delete all cookies belonging to a site by running an SQL `DELETE` command on this file:

*Linux / Mac*

```
sqlite3 cookiefile 'DELETE FROM cookies WHERE host_key LIKE "%domain%";'
```

*Windows*

```
sqlite3 cookiefile "DELETE FROM cookies WHERE host_key LIKE '%domain%';"
```

**Note**:
You can download the sqlite commandline client from here: https://sqlite.org/download.html

Comment: I'm getting "Error: disk I/O error" when attempting to delete a cookie. SELECT command with same where clause shows there's 1 cookie that would match. I guess it can't be deleted while browser is open? Running with admin privileges obviously.

Comment: The sqlite3 command didn't clear my cookies, but just deleting the file does.

Comment: With Edge it is: '...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default\Cookies' and 'Cookies-journal'. There are separate folders for the Developer and Beta versions, too.
As of today, all Edge processes must be terminated first. Just clearing the cookies in the UI does not seem to be sufficient.

Answer (score 7):

The wrench menu is gone now. In Sept 2014, the answer to the question of how to delete specific cookies in the Chrome Browser is:

- Go to menu button, choose "settings".
- Select "Show advanced settings".
- Go to "Privacy".
- Select "Content Settings" button.
- Under "Cookies" select the "all cookies and site data" button.

A shorter alternative to arrive at the same place as the above steps is to type the chrome URL directly into the address bar: `chrome://settings/content/cookies`, which can also be bookmarked for more convienient reuse, before proceeding onto the final steps:

- Search for the site you want to delete.
- Click the "X" to the right of the site listing.

Google sure has made this difficult. The headings that lead you here are non-intuitive, and it's way to buried, and by changing the location of this function in each version of Chrome, there are all kinds of out-dated answers on the web.

Comment: Thanks! This works great even now (June 2015) and doesn't need an additional browser addon.

Comment: In newer versions of chrome, the URL seems to be `chrome://settings/content/cookies` instead.

Comment: Looks like to delete specific cookies, you now go to: chrome://settings/content/all

Answer (score 6):

1. Open the *Wrench Menu*
2. Navigate to `Options -> Under the hood -> Content Settings -> Cookies`
3. Click `All cookies and site data…`
4. Search for the site
5. Click on the `[+]` to expand the site and view its cookies
6. You can delete either a specific cookie for the site or the site and *all* of its cookies

Comment: I think the Wrench Menu is gone now.

Answer (score 2):

[I use Cookie Monster](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/CookieMonster.php) for managing cookies for all my browsers, not just Chrome.

.

Answer (score 2):

This works on my system: `chrome://settings/content/all?search=privacy`

...presenting a list of per-site cookies with a search/filter text field in the top-right corner of the page, for my current version/context/date:

```
Google Chrome: 111.0.5563.64 (Official Build) (arm64)
OS: macOS Version 12.6.3 (Build 21G419)
date: 2023-03-15
```

Since it appears Google Chrome is changing its user interaction every so often (a few of the above answers did not work for me, including the most-up-voted answer), this might not work on other OSes or in future versions, but who knows.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [Cookie Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mkfjmbbghhjglaldohfnmccfofoogbik) extension.

Answer (score 1):

Consider use of cookies manages such as [ChromeCookieView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html) and [CookieSpy](http://download.cnet.com/CT-Cookie-Spy/3000-2144_4-10051296.html), (the CookieSpy developers appear to no longer have a web presence, but the product can be downloaded from numerous places, such as this link).

They are free. ChromeCookieView is very functional. CookieSpy shows cookies for not only for Chrome but and other browsers as well.