# Chrome 2023: How to delete specific cookies from a site?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

I googled a lot and didn't find anything. All topics refer to old Chrome versions. [For example also this one](https://superuser.com/questions/393932/delete-specific-cookies-from-google-chrome).

In the past it was possible to delete specific cookies on a site. Since couple of months this feature has been removed or moved somewhere, where I cannot find it.

Currently - Chrome `Version 114.0.5735.199` - I cannot remove specific cookies, I only see if the site uses cookies and I can delete them all.

Also, I didn't find any extension. The extension which is supposed to do it, does nothing.

IS there any way to delete specific cookies in the newest Chrome versions?

Comment: It is really a shame for chrome to remove the feature/possibility to delete specific cookies from a site. What they are thinking?! It's so useful. BTW, their offiical help,  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95647#zippy=%2Cdelete-cookies-from-a-site, still includes how to do it, which no longer work any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the extension
[Cookie-Editor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-editor/hlkenndednhfkekhgcdicdfddnkalmdm/) :

> Simple yet powerful Cookie Editor that allow you to quickly create, edit and delete cookies without leaving your tab.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Google do love to bury this particular feature away. Currently:

**Settings** -> **Privacy and Security** -> **Site Settings** -> **View permissions and data across all sites**

That last one is super easy to miss. Once you're on there you can search for sites and delete data for individual sites.